# Problem generating ddl in spring data jpa application

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, ddl

We have a working Spring Boot (2.1.3) application. For local development we use

```
  jpa:
     hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create-drop
```

Now we need to generate a ddl file for our db-guys (preferable during build). I'll tried by setting these additional properties:

```
  javax:
    persistence:
      schema-generation:
        create-source: metadata
        action: create
        create-target: create.sql
```

With these settings in place (ddl-auto changed to none) i started up my application. While it started fine there is not "create.ddl" to found.

Because i want the ddl file to be generated during build i added a test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:/testproperties/ddlgenerate.yml")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
public class GenerateDDL {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void generateDDL(){
        em.close();
        em.getEntityManagerFactory().close();
    }

}
```

I read somewhere that the ddl should be generated during instantiation of `EntityManager`?! 
The referenced `classpath:/testproperties/ddlgenerate.yml` only contains

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          schema-generation:
            create-source: metadata
            action: create
            create-target: create.sql
```

Log indicates that the properties are loaded. The test is green but still no ddl file.

So how to get a ddl file generated (preferable during build)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `@TestPropertySource` does not support yaml files as source. All is working as soon as yaml is converted to properties file.